# Need advice on retrofit shower threshold

Tags: bathroom, shower

We want to extend the height of the curb on our acrylic one-piece shower stall.  Unfortunately the corners of the shower's curb are rounded rather than square, and all retrofit thresholds we've seen online are designed for square corners.  Does anyone have a clever solution for us?

Comment: I'm having a hard time visualizing what you're proposing.  Perhaps a photo or two would help.

Comment: We just changed directions to resolve the issue.